# Dudas sobre CSS grid-column values

Tags: css, grid

Estoy experimentando un poco de Grid y quería saber como hacer para que, agregando o quitando columnas, grid-column siempre se mantenga de comienzo a fin.

Los valores pueden ser (por ejemplo) `grid-column 1 / 'last'`o si o si debe recibir valores numéricos?

La idea es que, independiente de la cantidad de columnas, siempre este de comienzo a fin.

Gracias!

Comment: explica mejor tu duda por favor

Comment: En pocas palabras quiero saber si puedo agregar 'last' como valor en grid-column para que siempre se mantenga de comienzo a fin o si o si es necesario que reciba un valor numerico, ejemplo: grid-column: 1 / 5.

Comment: Una opción es con javascript y obtener cuantas columnas tienes y siempre tomar la última.

Comment: Ah perfecto! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo:

```
grid-column: 1 /span last;

grid-column: 1 /sapn;

grid-column: 1 / -1;
```